# How to update meteor to 1.0rc.11

Tags: meteor

My meteor current version is 0.9.4, and I want to try the latest version "1.0-rc11", I've tried `meteor update —release 1.0-rc11` and `meteor update —release 1.0-rc.11`, and I always got this message "Your packages are at their latest compatible versions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have packages that are not compatible with the rc.

Meteor 1.0 is out. You may want to try that with `meteor update`.

Have a look at what the packages you have are and their constraints to find out whether they are compatible with 1.0. If you have older packages it might prevent an update until you sort them out.

You can check the packages you have in your app using `meteor list`